# How to give a div full height in CSS

Tags: css, height

I've got a test site here with two columns, both with absolute positioning.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17844821/zeug/heighttest.html

As you can see, the left column has more content than the right one, so that will cause scroll bars.
Since I want the right column to get the same height as the left one, I gave it `height: 100%` css property.

Now scroll down and you'll see what happens.
The right column expands to 100% of the browser window's height and not 100% height of the whole website.

How can I give both divs 100% full height? (Already tried `bottom: 0;` for the right div. Won't work.)

**Note:** .wrapper **must** stay with `position: absolute` as it is an requirement for my original whole website layout.

Comment: You should use floats instead of absolute positioning.

Comment: @Diodeus Ok, so here is a floated version. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17844821/zeug/heighttest2.html - Still has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only this:

```
body { overflow:auto; margin:0; }
.wrapper { display:table; width:100%; }
.left, .right { display:table-cell; width:50%; }
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, that looks like a really elegant solution but what if I need .wrapper to be positioned absolutely? When my web app starts, I use `top:-100%` to hide it. Then after clicking a link, I use jQuery to set `top:0` to slide it in via an animation transition.

Comment: Use opacity to hide elements, it is better. If you really need absolute, just do it in jQuery $('.left,.right').height(Math.max($('.left).height(),$('.right').height(),$(window).height()));

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need "wrapper", but if you leave it in, you need to make it 100% height as well.

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.red{
    background: red;
}

.blue{
    background: blue;
}

.wrapper{
height:100%
}

.left{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height:100%;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using tables.  Though I realize some people despise tables for anything other than data representation.

See dabblet for example:
http://dabblet.com/gist/2238394

CSS

```
.red{
    background: red;
}

.blue{
    background: blue;
}

.wrapper{
    overflow: auto;
    width:100%;
}
td{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="wrapper">
    <tr>
        <td class="red">
            foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo
        </td>
        <td class="blue">
            foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>foo
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I didn't vote down but I would agree that using tables isn't a good idea for creating a website layout because of the lack of semantics ("A table is a table is a table is a table").
Using div's with `display:table` and `display:table-cell` should probably be the way to achieve the same looking result although I am still testing my layout with these css attributes.

Comment: Right, hence the comment I made in my answer.  But I still don't see why this deserved a downvote.

Comment: I guess that's because table layouts are usually considered as "bad practice". It's an relict from html 3.2 web design. From what I've read so far in html books and online tutorials, one should always avoid table layouts which could be the reason why the downvoter didn't consider your suggestion as a good practice. However, as I already said, I didn't vote down, so this is just a guess.